# Changing the left-most optimization flag during compilation of code from Rcpp

Tags: c++, gcc, g++, rcpp

I've tried changing `~/R/Makevars`

```
C=/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/6.3.0/bin/gcc-6
CXX=/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/6.3.0/bin/g++-6
FC=/usr/local/bin/gfortran
F77=/usr/local/bin/gfortran

PKG_LIBS += -lboost_date_time-mt -fopenmp -lgomp
PKG_CFLAGS += -O3 -Wall -pipe -pedantic -std=gnu99 -fopenmp
CFLAGS += -O3 -Wall -pipe -pedantic -std=gnu99 -fopenmp -fopenmp
CXXFLAGS += -O3 -Wall -pipe -pedantic -fopenmp 
PKG_CXXFLAGS += -O3 -Wl,-stack_size,0x40000000,-stack_addr,0xf0000000
PKG_CPPFLAGS += -O3 -Wl,-stack_size,0x40000000,-stack_addr,0xf0000000
CXX11FLAGS += -O3 -Wall,-stack_size,0x40000000,-stack_addr,0xf0000000
```

to reflect the desired `-O3` optimization flag, but the left-most part of the compilation command is always `-fPIC  -g -O2 -c myCode.cpp -o myCode.o`. This triggers `g++-6` to compile using the `-O2` optimization level instead of `-O3`.

How do I fix this?

Comment: You cannot. You need to edit the `Makeconf` file.  It's an R limitation.

Comment: But you _can_ locally add `-march=native` and other non-portable choices.

Comment: Thanks! That fixed it. In case someone is wondering, you can find `Makeconf` by typing `file.path(R.home("etc"), "Makeconf")` in `R`.

Comment: Well, sure, yes -- there are several ways to query this; `R RHOME` gives you the root dir for R on the command-line.